# why does Firestore reflect the last field value?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Like this, I call the 3 functions:

```
DbMain db = new DbMain();

        db.openAccount("YOO","key_1",false);

        db.deposit(70, "Bank");
        db.deposit(70, "Bank");
```

The `openAccount` function, make an account and its balance is initialized as 0:

```
void openAccount(String ownerOfAccount, String key ,boolean savingsOrNot) //
     {
         mAuth.signInAnonymously();

         Account account = new Account(ownerOfAccount, key,"Account Number",0);
         if (savingsOrNot == true)
             db.collection("Info/Account/SavingsAccount").document(mAuth.getUid()).set(account);
         else
             db.collection("Info/Account/BankAccount").document(mAuth.getUid()).set(account);

         
     }
```

```
void deposit(int amount, String savingsOrBank) //     {
        DocumentReference accountRef;



            accountRef = db.collection("Info/Account/"+savingsOrBank+"Account").document(mAuth.getUid());

            accountRef.update("balance", FieldValue.increment(amount));
            
            accountRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task)
            {


                DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = task.getResult();

                Log.d("here!!!_deposit_1",documentSnapshot.get("balance").toString());

                AccountLog log = new AccountLog(true, amount,Integer.valueOf(documentSnapshot.get("balance").toString()), LocalDate.now(), LocalTime.now());
                addAccountLog( log, false);

                Log.d("here!!!_deposit_2",documentSnapshot.get("balance").toString());

            }
        });
    }
```

And the 'deposit' function add a money to field 'balance' as 'amount'
But the result here:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9e8u.png)
after first calling `deposit`, the field 'balance' already shows 140.
as expected, 'balance' value maybe is [openAccount]->0, [first deposit] ->70, [second deposit] ->140
But at three points, all 'balance' value are same as '140'.
I don't understand why.

Comment: If I understand correctly, after the second deposit your balance should be 210, but actually is showing 140, is that right?